# How to add iPad storyboard for project created for iPhone only?

Tags: ios, storyboard

I originally created the project with just the iPhone storyboard. But now I want to add the iPad storyboard.  But I am not certain how exactly to do that.

Would anyone be able to explain to me how to do that?

Comment: Please stop signing your posts. I thought about going through and nuking all the sigs, but got overwhelmed. Just in the future, don't sign them. Thanks :)

Answer (score 12, accepted):

Navigate to File > New > File > User Interface > Storyboard and then select iPad. This is how you will create the storyboard for the iPad.

Secondly, you have to iOS Application Target and select the Universal Type so it can also run on iPad.

Thirdly, you have to go to iPhone Storyboard and copy all by selecting all the content in it. Go into the iPad storyboard and paste it in.

It will create everything for you and it will run on your iPad as well. All the connections with the code that you have made in the iPhone StoryBoard will work in the iPad StoryBoard as well.

But as you can guess iPad has a bigger screen so you can build on top of it by adding other iPad only functionalities. But thats how you can get started.

Hope it helps!

Comment: Thanks that worked. I'll accept the answer in 8 min when SO allows me to do so.

Comment: Just used this answer on xCode 6. Not sure about other versions, but when I pasted the iPhone UI into the iPad storyboard, there was no Initial View Controller set. Just ticked the box on the navigation controller and all worked great.

Answer (score -1):

Xcode now creates the storyboard for you automatically when you change the "Devices" option under "Deployment Info" on the "General" tab of the target properties. You no longer have to copy it yourself.